# Is there a keyboard shortcut for multiple file selection?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there keyboard shortcut similar to `CTRL-LMB` ? If I have 10 files and I only want to select 3, I can hold `CTRL` and use left mouse button to select which files I want. Is there a keyboard shortcut for that? Something like using arrows keys, then pressing some shortcut to highlight the file, then pressing enter to do something with those selected files?

Comment: What OS are you referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to select a focused file or folder and  use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd> Keys to Move Around.

Additionally, you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd> to select multiple files if they are in a row.

Answer (score 2):

If you hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and navigate using the arrow keys, you can select individual files with the <kbd>Space</kbd> key.